# unable to install capybara-webkit on OS X El Capitan

Tags: ruby, qt, rubygems, osx-elcapitan

I am having problem with installing capybara-webkit after upgrading to El Capitan. QT version `qt-4.8.7_1` already installed. `bundle install` gives permission error and `sudo gem install` gives onother error:

bundle install:

```
~/P/m/web-automation (responsive ⚡=) bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/.........
Fetching version metadata from http://rubygems.org/...
Fetching dependency metadata from http://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...
....
Installing capybara-webkit 1.7.1 with native extensions

Errno::EACCES: Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/capybara-webkit-1.7.1/.gitignore
An error occurred while installing capybara-webkit (1.7.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install capybara-webkit -v '1.7.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

gem install:

```
~/P/m/web-automation (responsive ⚡=) sudo gem install capybara-webkit -v '1.7.1'
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing capybara-webkit:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/capybara-webkit-1.7.1
/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20151201-8173-19fj5gv.rb extconf.rb
cd src/ && /usr/local/bin/qmake /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/capybara-webkit-1.7.1/src/webkit_server.pro LIBS\ +=\ -L/usr/local/opt/libyaml/lib\ -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib\ -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -o Makefile.webkit_server
cd src/ && /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make -f Makefile.webkit_server
clang++ -pipe -stdlib=libc++ -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -O2 -arch x86_64 -Wall -W -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_WEBKIT_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/usr/local/Cellar/qt/4.8.7_1/mkspecs/unsupported/macx-clang-libc++ -I. -I/usr/local/Cellar/qt/4.8.7_1/lib/QtCore.framework/Versions/4/Headers -I/usr/local/Cellar/qt/4.8.7_1/lib/QtCore.framework/Versions/4/Headers -I/usr/local/Cellar/qt/4.8.7_1/lib/QtNetwork.framework/Versions/4/Headers -I/usr/local/Cellar/qt/4.8.7_1/lib/QtNetwork.framework/Versions/4/Headers -I/usr/local/Cellar/qt/4.8.7_1/lib/QtGui.framework/Versions/4/Headers -I/usr/local/Cellar/qt/4.8.7_1/lib/QtGui.framework/Versions/4/Headers -I/usr/local/Cellar/qt/4.8.7_1/lib/QtWebKit.framework/Versions/4/Headers -I/usr/local/Cellar/qt/4.8.7_1/lib/QtWebKit.framework/Versions/4/Headers -I/usr/local/Cellar/qt/4.8.7_1/include -Ibuild -F/usr/local/Cellar/qt/4.8.7_1/lib -x c++-header -c stable.h -o build/webkit_server/c++.pch
clang -pipe -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -O2 -arch x86_64 -Wall -W -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_WEBKIT_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/usr/local/Cellar/qt/4.8.7_1/mkspecs/unsupported/macx-clang-libc++ -I. -I/usr/local/Cellar/qt/4.8.7_1/lib/QtCore.framework/Versions/4/Headers -I/usr/local/Cellar/qt/4.8.7_1/lib/QtCore.framework/Versions/4/Headers -I/usr/local/Cellar/qt/4.8.7_1/lib/QtNetwork.framework/Versions/4/Headers -I/usr/local/Cellar/qt/4.8.7_1/lib/QtNetwork.framework/Versions/4/Headers -I/usr/local/Cellar/qt/4.8.7_1/lib/QtGui.framework/Versions/4/Headers -I/usr/local/Cellar/qt/4.8.7_1/lib/QtGui.framework/Versions/4/Headers -I/usr/local/Cellar/qt/4.8.7_1/lib/QtWebKit.framework/Versions/4/Headers -I/usr/local/Cellar/qt/4.8.7_1/lib/QtWebKit.framework/Versions/4/Headers -I/usr/local/Cellar/qt/4.8.7_1/include -Ibuild -F/usr/local/Cellar/qt/4.8.7_1/lib -x objective-c++-header -c stable.h -o build/webkit_server/objective-c++.pch
```

for full log: [enter link description here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qh0bhzxc2v641rf/gem_make.out?dl=0)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$ brew install qt
$ brew link --overwrite qt
$ bundle install
```

Worked for me (rbenv / Yosemite 10.10.5 (14F27))

Comment: This also worked for me, whereas the answer above did not. Thanks @rtrojanowski!

Comment: Awesome! @SemenyukDmitry Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 2):

In short:

```
$ brew upgrade
$ which qmake
$ rm `which qmake`
$ brew install qt5
$ brew link --force qt5
$ bundle install
```

Based on:

- [capybara-webkit が bundle install できなかった話](http://qiita.com/akito19/items/40f576ff4a90e9fad008)
- [OS X El Capitan 10.11 and Yosemite 10.10](https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/wiki/Installing-Qt-and-compiling-capybara-webkit#os-x-el-capitan-1011-and-yosemite-1010)

P.S. And as a principal workaround - use [Poltergeist](https://github.com/teampoltergeist/poltergeist). They have binary packets for any OS and 0 issues with installation.

Comment: doesnt work. `bundle install` still gives the same error.